# Calling TextView setText() from onTouchListener stucks UI

Tags: android, textview, handler, ui-thread

Here is my sample code:

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    float center = mScrubberX + mScrubberWidth / 2;
    float handleLeft = center - HANDLE_WIDTH;
    float handleRight = center + HANDLE_WIDTH;
    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (e.getX() > handleLeft && e.getX() < handleRight) {
                mActionDown = true;
                mActionDownX = e.getX() - mScrubberX;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float newLeft = e.getX() - mActionDownX;
            float newRight = newLeft + mScrubberWidth;

            if (mActionDown && !mIsStreaming) {
                if (newLeft > mScrubberContainer.getLeft() &&
                        newRight < mScrubberContainer.getRight()) {
                    mScrubberX = e.getX() - mActionDownX;
                    textView.setText(""+mScrubberX)
                } else if (newRight < mScrubberContainer.getRight()) {
                    mScrubberX = mScrubberContainer.getLeft();
                } else if (newLeft > mScrubberContainer.getLeft()) {
                    mScrubberX = mScrubberContainer.getRight() - mScrubberWidth;
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mActionDown = false;
            break;
        default:
            //Do nothing
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Please check line "textView.setText(""+mScrubberX)" struck the UI. I have tried putting this inside Handler, Asynctask.executor, runOnUIThread but nothing worked. 
Please suggest some solution to get rid of this issue.

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. It just struck the UI which I have invalidated from onTouchListener.

Comment: onTouch is getting called frequently which leads text view to draw the text again n again. Which seems to be the cause. But I want the text view update like this only.

Comment: do entire action MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE in background and update UI in main thread and check working or not.